# Bug with optional arguments in sagetex?

Tags: optional-arguments, sagetex

I can't seem to find where to report this bug, and I wanted to see if it was either known about, or repeatable by others.

When you compile sage code using the sagetex package it is suppose to generate 1 line per \sage call command in the $.sagetex.sout file. But if you have a sqrt with an optional argument (other functions with optional arguments I've tried seem to be ok) it creates a whole bunch of extra sage lines which end up throwing off all future sage code placements.

Try compiling the following code;

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
x = 5
y = 10
\end{sagesilent}
$\sqrt{\sage{x}}$

$\sqrt[3]{\sage{y}}$

$\sqrt[12]{\sage{x}}$

\end{document}
```

Strangely, if you compile that code the pdf looks right, but if you look at the .sout file it has a bunch of extra lines. Which may not matter on the face of it, but if you use another program that has sagetex integrated  with it, everything goes up in flames.

Is this duplicate code doing something, or is this a bug?